# How shall I attribute H1 tag to my post title in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

While posting articles on my WordPress website, I want my post title to show in H1 tag by default. What change do I need to carry in WordPress Theme

Comment: Can you show us more? Like the code and your configurations.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note that you are expected to have researched your issue and made attempts to solve it before posting. Questions should include a **summary of what you have tried so far and the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**. Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

This is an option that belongs to the theme, you have to create a child-theme and modify the partial/function that contains this markup (if the theme uses this option).

To better help you, you must tell what theme are using.